# What is the usage of Context.sol within ERC-20?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, erc20

When releasing the ERC-20 token,
OZ(OpenZeppelin)'s util ***Context.sol*** is inherited.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

/*
 * @dev Provides information about the current execution context, including the
 * sender of the transaction and its data. While these are generally available
 * via msg.sender and msg.data, they should not be accessed in such a direct
 * manner, since when dealing with meta-transactions the account sending and
 * paying for execution may not be the actual sender (as far as an application
 * is concerned).
 *
 * This contract is only required for intermediate, library-like contracts.
 */
abstract contract Context {
    function _msgSender() internal view virtual returns (address) {
        return msg.sender;
    }

    function _msgData() internal view virtual returns (bytes calldata) {
        return msg.data;
    }
}
```

I read that when using a meta-transaction solution such as ***EIP-2771***, Context.sol is useful.
https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/help-understanding-contract-context/10579

```
    function _msgSender() internal view virtual override returns (address sender) {
        if (isTrustedForwarder(msg.sender)) {
            // The assembly code is more direct than the Solidity version using `abi.decode`.
            assembly { sender := shr(96, calldataload(sub(calldatasize(), 20))) }
        } else {
            return super._msgSender();
        }
    }
```

But in the case of ERC-20, why shoud I use Context.sol's _msgSender()?

```
 function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        address owner = _msgSender();
        _transfer(owner, to, amount);
        return true;
    }
```

Doesn't make it more secure?

What is the usage of Context.sol within ERC-20?

***Thank you in advance.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context is needed to implement metatransactions, or gas free transactions for token transfers.

More about Context in [Gas Station Network documentation](https://docs.opengsn.org/contracts/#install-opengsn-contracts).

If you do not plan to support this feature (hint: no one does today) you do not need to `Context`.